# Is there an alternative to a video thumbnail frame?

Tags: grid, video, preview, thumbnail

I am designing an app for a piece of software. In a section of this very complex app, users can add photo/video/audio/excel/word files. Once uploaded, they can view them in a large thumbnail grid.

The problem is, to have a preview of the recorded video as the thumbnail image, it will take too long for the user to upload if on a anything other than an amazing device.

**Are there any other options I can use here without it just being an icon?**
Otherwise, we will have icons for every other file that's not a jpeg, which would look rubbish.

Or is there an easier way to code it?

Comment: Could you clarify, what does previewing files in a grid have to do with your upload functionality? Also, what kind of devices are you supporting?

Answer (score 1):

Most video platforms allow users to choose a 'poster frame' - a frame from the video content that can be used as a thumbnail. Facebook makes use of these when you post a youTube video.

The sound channel from the video could be used along with the poster frame to give an extremely lo-fi preview.

Some platforms also select keyframes from points in the video (usually at timed intervals) giving a slightly higher fidelity version (key frame images and sound only)

Other platforms use video formats that allow for multiple resolutions that enhance as they load (similar to they way JPEGs load on a really slow connection).